# What is the correct syntax for a set command within a mySQL user defined function?

Tags: mysql, function, syntax, user-defined-functions

I'm receiving the following error when trying to create a function in mySQL 5.1:

`Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 25
(0 ms taken)`

Here is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE
    FUNCTION removeMethodAndBackslash(input VARCHAR(40))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE loginName VARCHAR(40);
    SET loginName = input;

    IF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\b%' THEN
        SET loginName = 'b' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\n%' THEN
        SET loginName = 'n' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\t%' THEN
        SET loginName = 't' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\r%' THEN
        SET loginName = 'r' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSE
        SET loginName = SUBSTRING(input,7);

    RETURN loginName;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I've been playing with the syntax for a while and I'm certain its a very small detail that I'm overlooking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks manji...I'm new to stack overflow and I couldn't figure out how to block the entire code.

Comment: For clarification, I believe the error has to do with the set statements. Not sure though.

Comment: don't worry. You can look here:http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for markdown editing.

Comment: highlight a block of code and hit ctrl-K, or click the `{}` button in the editor's toolbar.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that next time. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE
    FUNCTION removeMethodAndBackslash(input VARCHAR(40))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE loginName VARCHAR(40);
    SET loginName = input;

    IF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\b%' THEN
        SET loginName = 'b' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSEIF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\n%' THEN
        SET loginName = 'n' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSEIF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\t%' THEN
        SET loginName = 't' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSEIF SUBSTRING(loginName,7) LIKE '\r%' THEN
        SET loginName = 'r' + SUBSTRING(input,8);

    ELSE
        SET loginName = SUBSTRING(input,7);
    END IF;

    RETURN loginName;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The difference with this code and my original code is the space between ELSE and IF, correct?

Comment: Ok...I've figured it out, there was a syntax error with the IF, ELSEIF, ELSE statements. I needed to add END IF; line. Thanks Devart.

Comment: Some notices (just about the above code): Try to optimize your function. E.g. - the result of SUBSTRING(loginName,7) can be stored once in a variable. Also you pass VARCHAR(40) as inpup variable, but returns VARCHAR(20); so, you string will be trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CASE...THEN...ELSE` block

```
DELIMITER $$  

CREATE FUNCTION removeMethodAndBackslash(input VARCHAR(40))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    BEGIN

    DECLARE loginName VARCHAR(40);

    SET loginName = 
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(input,7) LIKE '\b%' THEN 'b' + SUBSTRING(input,8)
            WHEN SUBSTRING(input,7) LIKE '\n%' THEN 'n' + SUBSTRING(input,8)
            WHEN SUBSTRING(input,7) LIKE '\t%' THEN 't' + SUBSTRING(input,8)
            WHEN SUBSTRING(input,7) LIKE '\r%' THEN 'r' + SUBSTRING(input,8)
            ELSE SUBSTRING(input,7)
       END;

    RETURN loginName;

END $$
```

Comment: I'd like to return the value in loginName. Is a RETURN command necessary? RETURN loginName; ?

Comment: first of all, you are checking `SUBSTRING(loginname,7) LIKE ..` not `SUBSTRING(input,7) LIKE ..`. It's not correct right? Then for your question, `RETURN loginName` is the result that will be returned by the function so when you do: `SELECT removeMethodAndBackslash('sdgdsdf\ndffgh')` you will have `'ndffgh'`.